# How to force a field update in an audited entity with envers?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I'm using Envers in order to know the last fields updates of my entities.

Sometimes I need to force (in the audit table) an update on a field (new revision: new date and boolean at true for this field) while this field has not changed.

Is it possible by default with Envers?

If not, can I extend the mechanism?

Comment: May be you can do a custom PostUpdate listener. (I know it's been two year but in case ...)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with Envers and I don't think there are any extension points which would allow that. The fields are compared using .equals().

Comment: Do you think I should not use envers and switch to a manual update date management ?

Comment: I don't know your use-case, and why you need the forced updates, so I can't answer that question.

Comment: We must advertise to a person when some fields are not updated since a long time. (we would like to use envers for that) This person can click a button to tell "it's ok, this field is again up to date".
That's why we need to do a new revision while the field has not changed

Comment: This looks a bit like a workflow, not auditing. I think you might be better off with a more workflow-like solution. Envers might work as well, but the "field touch" operation isn't available.